# SPLUNK Query : need to split a string in a list using delimiter

Tags: string, split, delimiter, splunk, splunk-query

eg: list = { abc::12345, xyz::345} . requirement is I have to get {abc, xyz} as query result.

needs stats count of the values in the list after removing the part after delimiter ::

Answer (score 0):

There's probably more than one way to do it (as is common with Splunk), but I like `rex`.  Here's a run-anywhere example query that shows how.

````
| makeresults 
| eval list = "{ abc::12345, xyz::345}" 
``` The above creates demo data.  Remove IRL ```
``` Use a regular expression to extract keywords from before "::" into field 'f' ```
| rex field=list max_match=0 "[\s\{,](?<f>[^:]+)" 
``` Count the number of (non-unique) values in f ```
| eval count=mvcount(f)
````